# Separate a string column depending on first character appearance

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to separate the column of a Spark DataFrame into 2 different columns depending on the first appearance of a character, which in this case is an underscore ("_").

I have prepared a 100% reproducible example:

The mock Spark DataFrame is:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
     (1, 1.8, 'newyork_3434_north'), 
     (4, 2.6, 'la_432432432_south'), 
     (6, 3.3, 'boston_234324_east'), 
     (8, 4.1, 'detroit_6757_west'), 
     (2, 5.7, 'miami_133123_north'), 
     (3, 6.2, 'atlanta_093394_west'), 
     (1, 6.1, 'houston_87342_east')
    ],
    ('ranking', "coordenate", "city")
)
```

The above code creates a table like the following one:

```
ranking  coordenate  city
1        1.8         newyork_3434_north
4        2.6         la_432432432_south
6        3.3         boston_234324_east
8        4.1         detroit_6757_west
2        5.7         miami_133123_north
3        6.2         atlanta_093394_west 
1        6.1         houston_87342_east
```

What I would like to do is separating the column city in 2 different columns depending on the location of the first underscore from left to right.

The final desired table would be then something like:

```
ranking  coordenate  city       code
1        1.8         newyork    3434_north
4        2.6         la         432432432_south
6        3.3         boston     234324_east
8        4.1         detroit    6757_west
2        5.7         miami      133123_north
3        6.2         atlanta    093394_west
1        6.1         houston    87342_east
```

I have seen several threads about this topic, but they do not speak about the first appearance of a character ([link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235704/split-spark-dataframe-string-column-into-multiple-columns), [link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283478/split-contents-of-string-column-in-pyspark-dataframe), etc.), but splitting by all specific characters that are on a string; or splitting by specific position of the character in the string.

I have also tried Python Pandas approach but as expected, it is not applicable in PySpark by extension or analogy ([link_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903557/splitting-on-first-occurrence))

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: how big's your dataframe? do you really need spark for this?

Comment: Hi @acushner, thanks for your reply. I agree with you, it seems very easy and in Pandas the solution is trivial (I already know how to do it locally), but the dataset is 123 GB. I have adapted a very easy and understandable data set in SO for this purpose, but it is a huge one, even selecting only the column that I want ("city"). Thanks in advance!

Comment: use split and concat_ws functions

Comment: Are there always exactly 2 underscores?

Comment: Hi @pault, the answer would be no. It is just coincidental in the example I illustrated; I have seen registries with more than 2 underscores in my SparkDF. Thank you for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best option here would be to use `pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract()` and `pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace()`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.select(
    "ranking",
    "coordenate",
    f.regexp_extract("city", pattern="^[A-Za-z]+(?=_)", idx=0).alias('city'),
    f.regexp_replace("city", "^[A-Za-z]+_", "").alias("code")
).show()
#+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
#|ranking|coordenate|      city|           code|
#+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
#|      1|       1.8|   newyork|     3434_north|
#|      4|       2.6|        la|432432432_south|
#|      6|       3.3|    boston|    234324_east|
#|      8|       4.1|   detroit|      6757_west|
#|      2|       5.7|     miami|   133123_north|
#|      3|       6.2|   atlanta|    093394_west|
#|      1|       6.1|   houston|     87342_east|
#+-------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

In both cases, the pattern is the essentially the same:

- `^[A-Za-z]+`: Match any number of letters starting at the beginning of the string
- `(?=_)`: Positive lookahead for an underscore

For `city` we find this pattern and extract the first match. For `code` we change the look-ahead to a match and replace the pattern with an empty string.

---

If finding an appropriate regular expression pattern is difficult, here is an alternative method that will work for Spark Version 2.1 and above:

Getting `city` is straightforward - you can use `pyspark.sql.functions.split()` to split the string on underscore and then use `getItem(0)` to get the first element of the split list.

For the `code` part, split the `city` on underscore and use `pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode()` to explode the resultant array. Then filter out for `pos > 0`, group by the original columns, and use `pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws` to join the collected tokens.

```python
df.select(
        "*",
        f.posexplode(f.split("city", "_")).alias("pos", "token")
    )\
    .where("pos > 0")\
    .groupBy("ranking", "coordenate", "city")\
    .agg(f.concat_ws("_" ,f.collect_list("token")).alias("code"))\
    .select(
        "ranking",
        "coordenate",
        f.split("city", "_").getItem(0).alias("city"),
        "code"
    )\
    .show()
```

Comment: Thanks @pault for your feedback. Amazing answer. Will mark it as answer of the question.

Answer (score 0):

@pault has already given an awsome answer using `regex` and `split` and `concat_ws` inbuilt functions

Heres an alternative of doing it simple using `udf` function as

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

@udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def splitUdf(x):
    splitted = x.split('_')
    return [splitted[0], '_'.join(splitted[1:])]

df.withColumn('city', splitUdf(col('city')))\
    .select(col('ranking'), col('coordenate'), col('city')[0].alias('city'), col('city')[1].alias('code'))\
    .show()
```

which should give you

```
+-------+----------+-------+---------------+
|ranking|coordenate|   city|           code|
+-------+----------+-------+---------------+
|      1|       1.8|newyork|     3434_north|
|      4|       2.6|     la|432432432_south|
|      6|       3.3| boston|    234324_east|
|      8|       4.1|detroit|      6757_west|
|      2|       5.7|  miami|   133123_north|
|      3|       6.2|atlanta|    093394_west|
|      1|       6.1|houston|     87342_east|
+-------+----------+-------+---------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful